# Is there a free utility which can adjust the white balance of Canon CR2 RAW files?

Tags: canon, software, windows, raw

For Nikon I can use the free `ViewNX` / `ViewNX 2` to adjust the white balance for NEF raw files.

Is there an equivalent from Canon for CR2 files (also free)?

Comment: Of course, I can use RawTherapee if Canon doesn't have a ViewNX equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Canon bodies comes with [Digital Photo Professional](http://www.usa.canon.com/dlc/controller?act=GetArticleAct&articleID=386), Canon's RAW converter which has White Balance adjustments (as well as plenty of other settings as well). The downside is that it's not free, per-se. I'm pretty sure you need to have the original software disk that comes with your Canon body in order to use the updates which are provided on Canon's website. So there is no direct link to download a standalone version of DPP.

There are ways to work around Canon's silly restriction, but I believe it's outside the scope of this question (though google is your friend).

Comment: I don't own a Canon, I just have a couple hundreds of CR2s from an in-door event, and they need some processing.

Comment: Can Lightroom 3 import them?

Comment: AFAIK, you can download the full DPP software form Canon website. If it is free without the product? That I am not sure about.

Answer (score 3):

Ufraw, either the stand alone version or as a plugin to Gimp, will do the job nicely.

Answer (score 3):

[Rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/) is powerful, free, and open-source.

You can download the full DPP (Digital Photo Professional) from Canon if you have the serial number of your camera. You need to start with the product page of your camera first:

http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_slr/eos_5d_mark_iii.aspx?type=download&language=EN